# Can't print a json value

Tags: python, json, websocket

i have this code in python whoose purpose is to send a text file .c .txt (whatever, i've been sending a helloworld.c) through a websocket.

The problem is when i test it, the code doesn't go beyond                 `print("I'm here!")`

```
 def onMessage_function(self, client_id, message): 
        print("Here's the message I received " + message + "\n\n\n")
        dumpedMSG = json.dumps(message)
        loadedMSG = json.loads(dumpedMSG)
        if 'file_name' in loadedMSG:
            print("I'm here!")
            print(loadedMSG['file_name'])
        else:
        # do something else here.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd print isn't reached? Maybe the `file_name` field is just empty?

Comment: you can also try pdb, `import pdb` and the `pdb.set_trace()` , this is the python debugger that would help you debug your program better, try using this see the object values.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but does this work?

```
def onMessage_function(self, client_id, message): 
    print("Here's the message I received " + message + "\n\n\n")
    loadedMSG = json.loads(message)
    if 'file_name' in loadedMSG:
        print("I'm here!")
        print(loadedMSG['file_name'])
    else:
    # do something else here.
```

In the original `loadedMSG` would be the same as `message`, so `'file_name' in loadedMSG` would be a substring check rather than a check for a dictionary key. The print after "I'm here!" would then throw an exception, which you might not see if you're only receiving what is sent over the socket.